# Copy a linked list in C from structure - function

Tags: c

I have a assignment and I just do not know how to do it, can someone help me?

There is linked list with criminals and they can have contacts on other criminals. I have 2 more functions, `addcontact` and `freelist`, but I need to make `clonelist` using just `createrecord`, or new function I make.I need to make a copy of linked list. First I need to copy the criminals and then contacts on them.
I need to keep this order: `createrecord`, `clonelist`,`addcontact`,`freelist`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct TCriminal
{
    struct TCriminal *m_Next;
    char *m_Name;
    struct TCriminal **m_Contacts;
    size_t m_Cnt;
    size_t m_Capacity;
} TCRIMINAL;

TCRIMINAL *createRecord(const char *name, TCRIMINAL *next)
{
    TCRIMINAL *newRecord = (TCRIMINAL *)malloc(sizeof(TCRIMINAL));
    if (newRecord == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    if (name == NULL || name[0] == '\0') {
        newRecord->m_Name = strdup("\0");
    } else {
        newRecord->m_Name = strdup(name);
    }
    if (newRecord->m_Name == NULL) {
        free(newRecord);
        return NULL;
    }
    newRecord->m_Next = next;
    newRecord->m_Contacts = NULL;
    newRecord->m_Cnt = 0;
    newRecord->m_Capacity = 0;
    return newRecord;
}

TCRIMINAL *cloneList(TCRIMINAL *src)
{
    if (src == NULL)
        return NULL;
    TCRIMINAL *newList = createRecord(src->m_Name, NULL);
    TCRIMINAL *currentOriginal = src->m_Next;
    TCRIMINAL *currentCopy = newList;
    TCRIMINAL *contactCopy;
    // Create a deep copy of the linked list
    while (currentOriginal != NULL)
    {
        currentCopy->m_Next = createRecord(currentOriginal->m_Name, NULL);
        currentCopy = currentCopy->m_Next;
        currentOriginal = currentOriginal->m_Next;
    }
    // Reset pointers for iteration
    currentOriginal = src;
    currentCopy = newList;
    // Copy contacts for each criminal
    while (currentOriginal != NULL)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < currentOriginal->m_Cnt; ++i)
        {
            TCRIMINAL *contact = currentOriginal->m_Contacts[i];
            TCRIMINAL *temp = newList;
            // Find the corresponding criminal in the copied list
            while (temp != NULL && strcmp(contact->m_Name, temp->m_Name) != 0)
                temp = temp->m_Next;
            // Add the contact to the copied list
            contactCopy = temp;
            temp = newList;
            // Find the corresponding criminal in the copied list
            while (temp != NULL && strcmp(currentOriginal->m_Name, temp->m_Name) != 0)
                temp = temp->m_Next;
            // Add the contact to the copied list
            if (temp != NULL && contactCopy != NULL)
            {
                if (temp->m_Contacts == NULL)
                {
                    temp->m_Capacity = 1;
                    temp->m_Contacts = (TCRIMINAL **)malloc(sizeof(TCRIMINAL *) * temp->m_Capacity);
                }
                else if (temp->m_Cnt == temp->m_Capacity)
                {
                    temp->m_Capacity *= 2;
                    temp->m_Contacts = (TCRIMINAL **)realloc(temp->m_Contacts, sizeof(TCRIMINAL *) * temp->m_Capacity);
                }
                temp->m_Contacts[temp->m_Cnt++] = contactCopy;
            }
        }
        currentOriginal = currentOriginal->m_Next;
        currentCopy = currentCopy->m_Next;
    }
    return newList;
}

void addContact(TCRIMINAL *dst, TCRIMINAL *contact)
{
    if (dst == NULL || contact == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    // Allocate memory for contacts if it's not allocated yet
    if (dst->m_Contacts == NULL)
    {
        dst->m_Capacity = 1;
        dst->m_Contacts = (TCRIMINAL **)malloc(sizeof(TCRIMINAL *) * dst->m_Capacity);
        if (dst->m_Contacts == NULL)
        {
            return; // Allocation failed
        }
        dst->m_Cnt = 0;
    }
    else if (dst->m_Cnt == dst->m_Capacity)
    {
        // Double the capacity if needed
        dst->m_Capacity *= 2;
        TCRIMINAL **newContacts = (TCRIMINAL **)realloc(dst->m_Contacts, sizeof(TCRIMINAL *) * dst->m_Capacity);
        if (newContacts == NULL)
        {
            return; // Reallocation failed
        }
        dst->m_Contacts = newContacts;
    }
    dst->m_Contacts[dst->m_Cnt++] = contact;
}

void freeList(TCRIMINAL *src)
{
    while (src != NULL)
    {
        TCRIMINAL *temp = src;
        src = src->m_Next;
        free(temp->m_Name);
        if (temp->m_Contacts != NULL)
        {
            free(temp->m_Contacts);
        }
        free(temp);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    TCRIMINAL *a, *b;
    char tmp[100];
    assert(sizeof(TCRIMINAL) == 3 * sizeof(void *) + 2 * sizeof(size_t));
    a = nullptr;
    a = createRecord("Peter", a);
    a = createRecord("John", a);
    a = createRecord("Joe", a);
    a = createRecord("Maria", a);
    addContact(a, a->m_Next);
    addContact(a->m_Next->m_Next, a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next);
    addContact(a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next, a->m_Next);
    assert(a
        && !strcmp(a->m_Name, "Maria")
        && a->m_Cnt == 1
        && a->m_Contacts[0] == a->m_Next);
    assert(a->m_Next
        && !strcmp(a->m_Next->m_Name, "Joe")
        && a->m_Next->m_Cnt == 0);
    assert(a->m_Next->m_Next
        && !strcmp(a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Name, "John")
        && a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Cnt == 1
        && a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Contacts[0] == a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next);
    assert(a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next
        && !strcmp(a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Name, "Peter")
        && a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Cnt == 1
        && a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Contacts[0] == a->m_Next);
    assert(a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next == nullptr);
    b = cloneList(a);
    strcpy(tmp, "Moe");
    a = createRecord(tmp, a);
    strcpy(tmp, "Victoria");
    a = createRecord(tmp, a);
    strcpy(tmp, "Peter");
    a = createRecord(tmp, a);
    addContact(b->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next, b->m_Next->m_Next);
    assert(a
        && !strcmp(a->m_Name, "Peter")
        && a->m_Cnt == 0);
    assert(a->m_Next
        && !strcmp(a->m_Next->m_Name, "Victoria")
        && a->m_Next->m_Cnt == 0);
    assert(a->m_Next->m_Next
        && !strcmp(a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Name, "Moe")
        && a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Cnt == 0);
    assert(a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next
        && !strcmp(a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Name, "Maria")
        && a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Cnt == 1
        && a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Contacts[0] == a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next);
    assert(a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next
        && !strcmp(a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Name, "Joe")
        && a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Cnt == 0);
    assert(a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next
        && !strcmp(a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Name, "John")
        && a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Cnt == 1
        && a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Contacts[0] == a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next);
    assert(a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next
        && !strcmp(a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Name, "Peter")
        && a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Cnt == 1
        && a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Contacts[0] == a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next);
    assert(a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next == nullptr);
    assert(b
        && !strcmp(b->m_Name, "Maria")
        && b->m_Cnt == 1
        && b->m_Contacts[0] == b->m_Next);
    assert(b->m_Next
        && !strcmp(b->m_Next->m_Name, "Joe")
        && b->m_Next->m_Cnt == 0);
    assert(b->m_Next->m_Next
        && !strcmp(b->m_Next->m_Next->m_Name, "John")
        && b->m_Next->m_Next->m_Cnt == 1
        && b->m_Next->m_Next->m_Contacts[0] == b->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next);
    assert(b->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next
        && !strcmp(b->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Name, "Peter")
        && b->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Cnt == 2
        && b->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Contacts[0] == b->m_Next
        && b->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Contacts[1] == b->m_Next->m_Next);
    assert(b->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next == nullptr);
    freeList(a);
    addContact(b->m_Next, b->m_Next);
    a = cloneList(b);
    assert(a
        && !strcmp(a->m_Name, "Maria")
        && a->m_Cnt == 1
        && a->m_Contacts[0] == a->m_Next);
    assert(a->m_Next
        && !strcmp(a->m_Next->m_Name, "Joe")
        && a->m_Next->m_Cnt == 1
        && a->m_Next->m_Contacts[0] == a->m_Next);
    assert(a->m_Next->m_Next
        && !strcmp(a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Name, "John")
        && a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Cnt == 1
        && a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Contacts[0] == a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next);
    assert(a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next
        && !strcmp(a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Name, "Peter")
        && a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Cnt == 2
        && a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Contacts[0] == a->m_Next
        && a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Contacts[1] == a->m_Next->m_Next);
    assert(a->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next == nullptr);
    assert(b
        && !strcmp(b->m_Name, "Maria")
        && b->m_Cnt == 1
        && b->m_Contacts[0] == b->m_Next);
    assert(b->m_Next
        && !strcmp(b->m_Next->m_Name, "Joe")
        && b->m_Next->m_Cnt == 1
        && b->m_Next->m_Contacts[0] == b->m_Next);
    assert(b->m_Next->m_Next
        && !strcmp(b->m_Next->m_Next->m_Name, "John")
        && b->m_Next->m_Next->m_Cnt == 1
        && b->m_Next->m_Next->m_Contacts[0] == b->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next);
    assert(b->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next
        && !strcmp(b->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Name, "Peter")
        && b->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Cnt == 2
        && b->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Contacts[0] == b->m_Next
        && b->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Contacts[1] == b->m_Next->m_Next);
    assert(b->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next->m_Next == nullptr);
    freeList(b);
    freeList(a);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code if you want anyone to read it! Also, that makes the structure clearer even to you yourself, helping you to find errors. Use your IDE's autoformatting feature for that. Further, extract a [mcve] from your code, don't put more than the necessary code in your question. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Someone else running code through a formatter does nothing for teaching the original poster how to better ask a question (and write readable code). Sigh.

Comment: I reformatted the code for readability.  I hope the indentation got lost in the process of copying the code and posting it to the question, especially since the `main` function seems to have been provided to you by the teaching environment.  You should definitely learn to indent and present the code in a readable and consistent fashion.

Comment: I restored the code you removed in the last edit.  The posted code works as expected. What is the problem in your test environment?  What error do you get?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: this is exaclty what the posted code does.  Then it proceeds to clone the contact lists too.  Apart from the error checking, the code works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for all comments, but still, It does not work, for some reason I have m_Contacts mismatch in testing environment (page I enter this). I cannot find the reason why it does not work, asserts are ok. It fails on some edge case and on random data.

Comment: A couple of side notes: `nullptr` is not a part of the C standard yet. `assert(sizeof(TCRIMINAL) == 3 * sizeof(void *) + 2 * sizeof(size_t));` is not guaranteed to work because of padding, and not needed.

Comment: This method will not work with a list that contains duplicate names. You can fix it easily by replacing `strcmp` with a direct comparison of pointers, e.g. `while (contact != temp) temp = temp->next;`

Comment: It seems that all you have is a linked list of _names_ --- criminals, `char*` ---  and other field that is an array of references --- `TCriminal**` --- to other _names_, other criminals (this could also be a linked list and use the same list implementation). Anyway, a linked list is not a list of names or criminals. It is a list of nodes. The nodes points to a data record or points to one. Merging data with the struct just makes things harder to implement, test and reuse.

Comment: I think you are creating a [_graph_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)). What representation is optimal in your programme depends on a few things such as the sparsity. Representing it as a linked-list on top of the graph is probably going to get you confused, eventually. Is the `addcontact` symmetric (graph _vs_ digraph)?

Comment: @arfneto I think you are missing an important part of this question. It is an assignment, and the *implementation* is checked and graded (as opposed to just the output).

Comment: @Neil I think you are missing an important part of this question. It is an assignment, and the *implementation* is checked and graded (as opposed to just the output).

Comment: Please, don't do this: `strdup("\0");` as every string literal has already a `'\0'` char at the end.  Just doing `strdup("");` will suffice.

Comment: It's tricky doing this robustly. The nodes (criminals) are elements of two graphs in parallel (linked-list and contacts), such that deleting a node affects the topology of _all_ the graphs at once. If you mix graphs, practically, in `freeList`, if you want to use other lists in the future, you must free all the indecent edges to that vertex first, (or else you get a pointer to a free vertex).

Answer (score 1):

Here are some remarks about the code:

- the function `createRecord` does not need to make a special case of the empty string and `strdup("\0")` behaves exactly the same as `strdup("")`.  `"\0"` is an empty string with 2 null terminators, the explicit one `\0` is redundant and useless in this case.

  Here is a simplified version:

  ```
  TCRIMINAL *createRecord(const char *name, TCRIMINAL *next)
  {
      TCRIMINAL *newRecord = (TCRIMINAL *)malloc(sizeof(TCRIMINAL));
      if (newRecord == NULL) {
          return NULL;
      }
      newRecord->m_Name = strdup(name ? name : "");
      if (newRecord->m_Name == NULL) {
          free(newRecord);
          return NULL;
      }
      newRecord->m_Next = next;
      newRecord->m_Contacts = NULL;
      newRecord->m_Cnt = 0;
      newRecord->m_Capacity = 0;
      return newRecord;
  }
  ```

  Also note that `createRecord` inserts the new record at the beginning of the list, which is the expected behavior according to the test cases, but is not intuitive for the casual reader.
- your function `cloneList` does use `createRecord` as requested but it does not check for failures, it should also use `addContact` to avoid duplicating the array allocation logic.  It could also preallocate the contact lists to avoid potential reallocation, but this is optional.
- in the second loop, you try and locate the criminal in the `newList` with the same name as `currentOriginal->m_Name`.  This seems redundant as it should be `currentCopy` (or a previous node in case of duplicates, which are probably not allowed).  You should just use `addContact(currentCopy, contactCopy)`.

  Here is a simplified version:

  ```
  TCRIMINAL *cloneList(TCRIMINAL *src)
  {
      if (src == NULL)
          return NULL;

      TCRIMINAL *newList = createRecord(src->m_Name, NULL);
      if (newList == NULL) // should complain?
          return NULL;
      TCRIMINAL *currentOriginal = src->m_Next;
      TCRIMINAL *currentCopy = newList;
      // Create a deep copy of the linked list
      while (currentOriginal != NULL)
      {
          currentCopy->m_Next = createRecord(currentOriginal->m_Name, NULL);
          if (currentCopy->m_Next == NULL) {
              freeList(newList);
              return NULL;
          }
          currentCopy = currentCopy->m_Next;
          currentOriginal = currentOriginal->m_Next;
      }
      // Reset pointers for iteration
      currentOriginal = src;
      currentCopy = newList;
      // Copy contacts for each criminal
      while (currentOriginal != NULL)
      {
          for (size_t i = 0; i < currentOriginal->m_Cnt; ++i)
          {
              TCRIMINAL *contact = currentOriginal->m_Contacts[i];
              TCRIMINAL *temp = newList;
              // Find the corresponding criminal in the copied list
              while (temp != NULL && strcmp(contact->m_Name, temp->m_Name) != 0)
                  temp = temp->m_Next;
              // Add the contact to the copied list
              if (temp != NULL)
              {
                  addContact(currentCopy, temp); // cannot test for failure
              }
          }
          currentOriginal = currentOriginal->m_Next;
          currentCopy = currentCopy->m_Next;
      }
      return newList;
  }
  ```
- if you must keep the functions in the same order and cannot use `createContact` from `cloneList` (what a pity), then you can preallocate the contact list and set the copies as you go:

  Here is an alternate version:

  ```
  TCRIMINAL *cloneList(TCRIMINAL *src)
  {
      if (src == NULL)
          return NULL;

      TCRIMINAL *newList = createRecord(src->m_Name, NULL);
      if (cnewList == NULL)
          return NULL;
      TCRIMINAL *currentOriginal = src->m_Next;
      TCRIMINAL *currentCopy = newList;
      // Create a deep copy of the linked list
      while (currentOriginal != NULL)
      {
          currentCopy->m_Next = createRecord(currentOriginal->m_Name, NULL);
          if (currentCopy->m_Next == NULL) {
              freeList(newList);
              return NULL;
          }
          currentCopy = currentCopy->m_Next;
          currentOriginal = currentOriginal->m_Next;
      }
      // Reset pointers for iteration
      currentOriginal = src;
      currentCopy = newList;
      // Copy contacts for each criminal
      while (currentOriginal != NULL)
      {
          if (currentOriginal->m_Cnt) {
              currentCopy->m_Contacts = (TCRIMINAL **)malloc(sizeof(TCRIMINAL *) * currentOriginal->m_Capacity);
              if (currentCopy->m_Contacts == NULL)
              {
                  freeList(newList);
                  return NULL;
              }
              currentCopy->m_Capacity = currentOriginal->m_Capacity;
              for (size_t i = 0; i < currentOriginal->m_Cnt; ++i)
              {
                  TCRIMINAL *contact = currentOriginal->m_Contacts[i];
                  TCRIMINAL *temp = newList;
                  // Find the corresponding criminal in the copied list
                  while (temp != NULL && strcmp(contact->m_Name, temp->m_Name) != 0)
                      temp = temp->m_Next;
                  // Add the contact to the copied list
                  if (temp != NULL)
                  {
                      currentCopy->m_Contacts[currentCopy->m_Cnt++] = temp;
                  }
              }
          }
          currentOriginal = currentOriginal->m_Next;
          currentCopy = currentCopy->m_Next;
      }
      return newList;
  }
  ```